# Emulate apt-get from third-party sources with dpkg

Tags: apt, deb

I am non-root user. Mu `sudoers` file allows me to `sudo apt-get install` and to `sudo dpkg`. So basically I can install any *.deb files, which I rarely need to do because I can get most stuff with `apt-get install`.

Sometimes there is a package I want to install that is not on one of the sources listed in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I can not write to `/etc/apt` and I can not `sudo apt-key add`.

So my question is: given a package repository, is there a way for a non root user to download a particular package as a *.deb file plus all the (missing) dependencies as *.deb files (and install them)? Will this mess something up?

Example:

How I install the packages warsow and warsow-data from `http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb games`

This is just an example package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can boot a live system I guess in your case it might be the best procedure, to perform your tasks in there and then transfer your downloaded packages over.

The following is regarding using a live-dvd (with a stick it should be more easy as long as you made it use the free space as persistent storage).

Boot your live-dvd and select 'try ubuntu', when finished attach a usb-stick. Open `gnome-disk-utility`, find your usb-device and unmount it, also write down it's device-path (for this example we will use /dev/sdb1).

Now open a terminal with `Ctr-Alt-t` and type `sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/apt/archives/` this will take care that this directory truly exists.

In the same terminal, you now mount the usb-stick to that point `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /var/cache/apt/archives` (be sure to use the correct device).

So now we will add the repository holding the software you want:

- for classic deb-archives:
  `sudo echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb games" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb-games.list` add the pgp-key `wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -`
- for ppa's: `sudo apt-add-repository someppa/ppa`

Now we update our package lists `sudo apt-get update` and download the packages `sudo apt-get install -d warsow`; the -d options makes apt-get only download the package and all dependencies.

Voila finished, all your needed packages are now on your stik. Reboot into your normal system, attach the stick, open a terminal and cd into the stick and there issue `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` to manually install all packages and then run `sudo apt-get install -f` to clean everything up.

This procedure can bring in newer versions of already installed packages depending what repositories you use, so be careful, what you download and install. With third-party repositories there is also always the probability to catch yourself a flu or a virus, so think about what you do.

Comment: To clarify: I aware that I can install any deb package once I have it. My question is about getting those packages, given an apt source and package name.

Comment: give my an example and I'll try to show you

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: rewrote the answer, this might also be possible with a virtualmachine and passing through a usb-stick.

Comment: plus are you sure you want to mess with this system?  why not ask your sysadmin/dad/mom? - oh yeah it is due to warsow ;)

Comment: Thank you! You are right, that all this is questionable. :p I had the idea to use a docker container to download the files and the I realized that I could just as well run my forbidden accounting software in docker. Still good to know how to do this in principle.